# Screen freezes when trying to show ImageView in full screen using Glide

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-glide

I am using the Glide library to show my image in the full screen...

It is working properly in one of my projects but when I try to use the same in another project it shows some error, So I changed code as shown below. Now app freezes with error

```
WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
```

BEFORE CODE

```
  Glide.with(ctx)
                .load(new File(items.get(position).getCompletePath()))
                .crossFade()
                .listener(new RequestListener<File, GlideDrawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onException(Exception e, File model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, File model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .into(holder.thumbnailImageView);
```

PRESENT CODE

```
Glide
        .with(ctx)
        .load(new File(items.get(position).getCompletePath())).listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLoadFailed( GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        return false;
    }
})
        .into(holder.thumbnailImageView);
```

How can I solve this issue? Any suggestions.

Comment: it is related to memory issue so let me ask u two questions please, what is the size of ur image? and what is your phone memory size?

Comment: 4GB RAM & 64GBB

Comment: what's the resolution of your image?

Comment: what about the image itself? (resolution)

Comment: try to play with the width and height of your image using Glide like this : `Glide.with(ctx).load(new File(items.get(position).getCompletePath())).listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>(1800, 1800)`, change 1800 to any value you want but make it smaller than the image's size